# Folding over Rose Tree

Tags: haskell

Given the following Algrebaic Data Structure:

```
data Tree a = Node {
    rootLabel :: a,
    subForest :: [Tree a]
}  deriving (Show)
```

and `fold`:

```
treeFold :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
treeFold f (Node x ts) = f x (map (treeFold' f) ts)
```

How can I get an `[a]` from a `Tree a`?

Comment: While your question has already been answered, I've still chosen to indicate that this is a poor question, in particular because "It shows no research effort" (quoted from the alt-text of the downvote arrow).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, @bheklir. I should've shown my attempt - which I found to be a poor one. That's what prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: Even a poor attempt is an attempt ;)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean using fold? You can get a function `Tree a -> [a]` pretty straightforward:

```
collapse :: Tree a -> [a]
collapse (Node x ts) = x : (concat $ map collapse ts)

Prelude> let t = Node 3 [Node 2 [], Node 4 [], Node 6 []]
Prelude> collapse t
[3,2,4,6]
```

If you specifically want to use `fold`, I guess you could do something similar:

```
collapse' :: Tree a -> [a]
collapse' = treeFold (\x tss -> x : (concat tss))

Prelude> collapse' t
[3,2,4,6]
```

I personally think the first version is clearer.

Comment: and `join` === `concat . map`, yea?

Comment: If you're referring to `join :: m (m a) -> m a` from the `Control.Monad` module, then that doesn't have the same signature as `concat . map :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`